# Get URL with iFrame

Tags: javascript, facebook, iframe

First thanks for time to try resolve this issue.

Situation:

We're testing a new advertising company ( FB ). I can get this code:

```
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.Event.subscribe(
          'ad.loaded',
          function(placementId) {
            console.log('Audience Network ad loaded');
          }
        );
        FB.Event.subscribe(
          'ad.error',
          function(errorCode, errorMessage, placementId) {
            console.log('Audience Network error (' + errorCode + ') ' + errorMessage);
          }
        );
      };
      (function(d, s, id) {
        var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
        js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.ad.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.5&appId=1669841419940219";
        fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
      }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script> 
    <div class="fb-ad" data-placementid="1669841419940219_1669841953273499" data-format="300x250" data-testmode="false"></div>
```

If i integrate this code in my website ( example.com ) the code are working fine.

The problem is when i include this code in my own AdServer.
Example:
Adserver.com -> iFrame (src ) - > Charge html FB code.

In this case FB code can't access to example.com because only detect the adserver.com and not get the real URL ( example.com )

How can i resolve this? I can't change the set up from my adserver for deleted iframe.

Maybe including any code in FB code? I don't know.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: If the code is run inside a document that is loaded from adserver.com, then that domain must be in your app settings: otherwise the SDK will refuse to work.

Comment: Are you refer we need bypass the adserver.com domain to SDK right?

The issue is don't know how can i bypass the adserver.com to FB SDK code.

Comment: I have no idea what you mean by “bypassing a domain.” / Again, the SDK will only run on domains configured in the app settings. So if your code – the actual HTML document that contains the JS that embeds the SDK, whether that be displayed in an iframe or not – gets served from the domain `adserver.com` (still not very clear from your description), then that domain has to be in your app settings.